# Beautiful Soup - Is it possible to limit searches to a certain area

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am searching a page for certain keywords and returning values contained in the container of class `ds_data`. My page has multiple keyword matches but I only want to return matches from a certain container labelled `<div id="tabsBody" class="tabsBody">`

Is there a way to tell Beautiful Soup I only want to search from there, I have tried

```
ds_data = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tabsBody'}.findNext(text=pattern).findNext('div', {'class': 'ds_data'})
```

but that fails

**My Code**

```
keyword_list = [

'USB 2.0 ports quantity',
'USB 3.0 ports quantity',
'VGA',
'Internal memory'

]


#Iterate through our keyword list and return the results
for search_text in keyword_list:
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % search_text)
    ds_data = soup.find(text=pattern).findNext('div', {'class': 'ds_data'})
    if ds_data.find('img', {'class': 'spacer_top n-sign'}):
        result_text = '0'
    elif ds_data.find('img', {'class': 'spacer_top y-sign'}):
        result_text = 'Yes'
    else:
        result_text = ds_data.text
    print search_text, result_text
```

Comment: The HTML is massive and wouldn't fit in, tried to shorten everything as much as I could.

Comment: it is impossible to really answer the question without seeing a html block and expected results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code (**copied verbatim with the syntax error from the question**)

```
ds_data = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tabsBody'}
       .findNext(text=pattern)
       .findNext('div', {'class': 'ds_data'})
```

certainly fails as it is trying to call a method `findNext` on a python dictionary; a `dict()` object has no such method.

But indeed `soup.find` returns a new soup that you can search, thus:

```
divsoup = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tabsBody'})
ds_data = divsoup.find(text=pattern).findNext('div', {'class': 'ds_data'})
```

Will return matches from only within the `<div class="tabsBody"></div>` element. Notice that `findNext` will navigate the tree into siblings and so while `find` will navigate into child nodes only.

Also any of these methods with names in singular (not containing all) return `None` on matches, so indeed you need to check the return value if you are not certain of the contents.

Comment: That worked really well and decreased my codes execution time dramatically too :)

Comment: just check for the None from each find method... or use the array versions.